# System.TimeZoneNotFoundException on ViewPage using ServiceStack.Razor

Tags: c#, servicestack, razorengine, servicestack-text

I have created a view using [Servicestack.Razor.](http://razor.servicestack.net/) On the view page I am trying to get the session using following code.

```
var session = GetSession<AuthUserSession>().ToJson();
```

When I put this code on the view page, I get following error:

```
System.TimeZoneNotFoundException
Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
```

StackTrace is as below:

```
Exception stack trace:
      at System.TimeZoneInfo.get_Local () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is this a bug in `Servicestack.Text`? How can I solve this?

Note: I am using Mono 3.0.10 on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error while working on a project. In my case it was because I did not have a properly exported TZ environment variable. I had to add the following to my UI init shell script:

```
read TZ 2>/dev/null < /etc/timezone
export TZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Mono has a known & longstanding [Timezone bug that affects Windows](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11817) but it SHOULD work in Linux as long as the TimeZone database is installed at /usr/share/zoneinfo. However, that's exactly the same error I get in Windows if I try to serialize a date, so that would make me think that for some reason, /usr/share/zoneinfo is out of place.

If it's NOT there, the workaround in [Comment 6](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11817#c6) may help you. But then I believe you have to resort to building ServiceStack.Text from sources so you can apply the workaround.

It might be easier to create a symbolic link at /usr/share/zoneinfo that points to wherever it actually *is* installed.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core defers to the OS for timezone-related operations and unfortunately Windows and Linux have different timezone names. Use [TimeZoneConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneConverter/) to convert between them, if needed.

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    timeZoneName = TZConvert.WindowsToIana(timeZoneName);
}
var zoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
```